# Invalid css error when using lumx

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, lumx

I have added lumx to my existing project in which I used [angular-material](http://material.angularjs.org/#/) . I have used to bower to install lumx referring [link](http://ui.lumapps.com/getting-started/installation) .But after the addition I am getting the following error .

```
"Syntax error: Invalid CSS after \" eot\": expected \")\", was \": \"#{$file-pa...\"\A on line 22 of /var/www/Browndesk/app/bower_components/bourbon/app/assets/stylesheets/helpers/_font-source-declaration.scss\A from line 13 of /var/www/Browndesk/app/bower_components/bourbon/app/assets/stylesheets/_bourbon.scss\A from line 7 of /var/www/Browndesk/app/styles/main.scss"
```

Please Help .

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with Bourbon, not with Lumx.

Source of error: `app/bower_components/bourbon/app/assets/stylesheets/_bourbon.scss`

Odds are bourbon is trying to parse some SCSS that it thinks is invalid.

Comment: If possible lose the bourbon dependency.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your sass compiler. I had the same problem when doing sass compile via compass. I switched to using sass compiler without compass and that solved it for me.

Comment: Can you help me with that  ? where can i find the sass compiler without compass

Comment: You can install it via command line similar to how you probably installed compass. Go to the sass docs for latest installation instructions [SASS install](http://sass-lang.com/install)

Answer (score 0):

I Had the same problem. I solved it by updating my sass compiler.
check your sass version and run:

```
gem install sass
```

Comment: Which versions are you using? I'm getting this error with most recent lumx,sass and bourbon.